# Riemann-Roch and sum of powers

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective $n$-fold and $L$ be a line bundle on $X$. We have Riemann-Roch formula,

when $n=1$,$\chi(L)=\chi(\mathcal{O}_X)+\mathrm{deg}(L)$,

when $n=2$,$\chi(L)=\chi(\mathcal{O}_X)+\frac{L(L-K)}{2}$,

when $n=3$, $\chi(L)=\chi(\mathcal{O}_X)+\frac{L(L-K)(2L-K)}{12}+\frac{L.c_2(X)}{12}$,

the fomula resembles sum of powers

$\sum_1^n k^0=n$, $\sum_1^n k^1=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and $\sum_1^nk^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

Is this a coincidence or they are related in general?

Comment: Should the first case be $n=1$?

Comment: Where did you get these formulae? There is the Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch theorem which computes $\chi$ of a vector bundle on a smooth variety, then in more generality there is the Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch theorem, which computes the analogous invariant for a flat, bounded complex of coherent sheaves (flat over a base) on a flat family of schemes. But I think you just need HRR; the combinatorial similarity comes from the presence of the Todd class of the tangent bundle in the formula. It's a mess, there are Bernoulli numbers involved...but it's fairly straightforward on the formal side.